# Visible, invisible button shape vba

Tags: vba, button, shapes, visible, invisible

I want to add a shape using a multifunction button.
First click should show the shape
Second click should hide the shape

Can I do that with one shape button?

```vb
Sub HideShape()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Shape1").Visible = False
End Sub
Sub UnhideShape()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("shape 1").Visible = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure

```
Sub HideOrShowButton()
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Shape1").Visible = False Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Shape1").Visible = True
Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Shape1").Visible = False
End if
End Sub
```

The sub checks if the shape is invisible, and if so, it makes it visible. If not, it hides the shape instead.

I advise you to **not use** `ActiveSheet`, and use a sheet codename (preferably) or name/index instead. Referring to objects with `Activate` or `Select` should generally be avoided.

Comment: That's  perfect, Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub HideShowShape()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Shape1").Visible = Not ActiveSheet.Shapes("Shape1").Visible
End Sub
```